# A referenced project's pdb file not in this projects application files list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF solution that contains three projects, MyApp, MyAppAdmin and MyAppLibrary. MyAppLibrary is referenced by the other two.

I need to be able to include MyAppLibrary.pdb when I publish MyApp (click once) but it does not show up in the projects Application Files even with "Show all files" checked.

If I open the Application Files for MyAppAdmin and have Show all files checked MyAppLibrary.pdb is in the list.

Any idea as to why the difference and/or how I can get it into the list for MyApp?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what type of projects you have, so I can't confirm that this will work for you. If you have a web project, then you should be able to uncheck the *Exclude generated debug symbols* option on the *Publish Web* property page in Visual Studio.

Failing that, you can try to set that value directly in the project file. Right click your project file in a Windows Explorer window and edit in a text editor. You can add a new `PropertyGroup` with this value to the end of the file (within the `Project` element) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>False</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
  <PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: MyApp and MyAppAdmin are WPF, MyAppLibrary is a Class Library. Adding the three lines of code to the end of the MyApp project file didn't work. VS wouldn't load the project.

Comment: Ah yeah, that won't work with WPF. That's a strange problem you have there. I checked and my `.pdb` files can be included in my *Application Files* when I tick the *Show all files* option. There *must* be an option somewhere to turn it off, but I'm sorry, I couldn't find one for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue is related to what solution platform is used. We need to run the application in 32 bit mode due to some dependancies we have. When this was originally setup we created a custom solution platform for some reason where MyAppLibrary and MyAppAdmin used the Any CPU platform but MyApp used x86. I switced to using the Any CPU for all of them and then specifying in each project to target the x86 platform.

Once this was done I know can see and include MyLibrary.pdb in the published output.

Dave